# Get another value from MySQL database on row

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, authentication

I have made a simple login and registration system (http://dak.esy.es/login/), and would like to retrieve other information from the same row in the MySQL database. Currently, only the username is saved (as `$_SESSION['username']`), and this is what is entered on the login page. On the database, the data I want to be saved is `id`, `fullname` and `email` - preferably in the same format as the username  (`$_SESSION['(name here)']`). I already have a file to connect to the database called `db.php`. If anyone could provide the code I would be greatly pleased.
The code on my `login.php` page is:

```
  <?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
//Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: ./index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
    }
        else{
            echo "<div class='form'><br/><h3>Username or password incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>try again</a></div>";
        }
}
?>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: your query must to select all attributes you want, you need to specify * for all or set its names

Comment: @ReneLimon I don't understand what you mean. Would you be able to provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what the requirement is: but i hope, you want every value from db row as session..
hope you have session:  `$_SESSION['username'] after login;

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_login` WHERE `username` = ".$_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['id'] = $row["id"];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row["fullname"];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
mysqli_close($conn);
```

or for setting session along with login validation:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_login` WHERE `username` = ".$_POST['username']." AND `password`= ".$POST['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(isset($row)){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row["id"];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row["fullname"];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
} else {
    redirect('login.php');   //reload login page on failure
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

this is the basic code and you can split this code to MVC.